# Fastai v2 IndexError: Target 2 is out of bounds

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, transformer-model, fast-ai

#### Package version and reference page

Hi, I am referring to the page [Blurr](https://github.com/ohmeow/blurr) to combining the HuggingFace Transformers' models with the Fastai fine-tuning policies. Below are the versions of the packages:

- transformers : 4.2.2
- fastai : 2.1.10
- ohmeow-blurr  : 0.0.22

The difference between the sample code in [Blurr](https://github.com/ohmeow/blurr) and mine is that I am trying to solve the **multi-class single label text classification** problem with 4 class of total labels while the tutorial is the **binary-classification** issue.

The dataset for both training and validation has 3 columns: texts, label, is_valid.

- **texts** contains text data similar to the [Blurr](https://github.com/ohmeow/blurr).
- **label** contains 4 classes of string labels, for each raw, there is only one label.
- **is_valid** contains bool value "True and False" that indicates if these raw are for training or validation.

#### Error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-fc93db149c6f> in <module>
     13 learn.freeze()
     14 
---> 15 learn.fit_one_cycle(3, lr_max=1e-3)

~/fastai/fastai/callback/schedule.py in fit_one_cycle(self, n_epoch, lr_max, div, div_final, pct_start, wd, moms, cbs, reset_opt)
    110     scheds = {'lr': combined_cos(pct_start, lr_max/div, lr_max, lr_max/div_final),
    111               'mom': combined_cos(pct_start, *(self.moms if moms is None else moms))}
--> 112     self.fit(n_epoch, cbs=ParamScheduler(scheds)+L(cbs), reset_opt=reset_opt, wd=wd)
    113 
    114 # Cell

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in fit(self, n_epoch, lr, wd, cbs, reset_opt)
    204             self.opt.set_hypers(lr=self.lr if lr is None else lr)
    205             self.n_epoch = n_epoch
--> 206             self._with_events(self._do_fit, 'fit', CancelFitException, self._end_cleanup)
    207 
    208     def _end_cleanup(self): self.dl,self.xb,self.yb,self.pred,self.loss = None,(None,),(None,),None,None

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    153 
    154     def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 155         try:       self(f'before_{event_type}')       ;f()
    156         except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    157         finally:   self(f'after_{event_type}')        ;final()

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in _do_fit(self)
    195         for epoch in range(self.n_epoch):
    196             self.epoch=epoch
--> 197             self._with_events(self._do_epoch, 'epoch', CancelEpochException)
    198 
    199     def fit(self, n_epoch, lr=None, wd=None, cbs=None, reset_opt=False):

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    153 
    154     def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 155         try:       self(f'before_{event_type}')       ;f()
    156         except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    157         finally:   self(f'after_{event_type}')        ;final()

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in _do_epoch(self)
    189 
    190     def _do_epoch(self):
--> 191         self._do_epoch_train()
    192         self._do_epoch_validate()
    193 

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in _do_epoch_train(self)
    181     def _do_epoch_train(self):
    182         self.dl = self.dls.train
--> 183         self._with_events(self.all_batches, 'train', CancelTrainException)
    184 
    185     def _do_epoch_validate(self, ds_idx=1, dl=None):

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    153 
    154     def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 155         try:       self(f'before_{event_type}')       ;f()
    156         except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    157         finally:   self(f'after_{event_type}')        ;final()

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in all_batches(self)
    159     def all_batches(self):
    160         self.n_iter = len(self.dl)
--> 161         for o in enumerate(self.dl): self.one_batch(*o)
    162 
    163     def _do_one_batch(self):

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in one_batch(self, i, b)
    177         self.iter = i
    178         self._split(b)
--> 179         self._with_events(self._do_one_batch, 'batch', CancelBatchException)
    180 
    181     def _do_epoch_train(self):

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    153 
    154     def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 155         try:       self(f'before_{event_type}')       ;f()
    156         except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    157         finally:   self(f'after_{event_type}')        ;final()

~/fastai/fastai/learner.py in _do_one_batch(self)
    164         self.pred = self.model(*self.xb)
    165         self('after_pred')
--> 166         if len(self.yb): self.loss = self.loss_func(self.pred, *self.yb)
    167         self('after_loss')
    168         if not self.training or not len(self.yb): return

~/fastai/fastai/losses.py in __call__(self, inp, targ, **kwargs)
     31         if targ.dtype in [torch.int8, torch.int16, torch.int32]: targ = targ.long()
     32         if self.flatten: inp = inp.view(-1,inp.shape[-1]) if self.is_2d else inp.view(-1)
---> 33         return self.func.__call__(inp, targ.view(-1) if self.flatten else targ, **kwargs)
     34 
     35 # Cell

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    959 
    960     def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 961         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
    962                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
    963 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2460         tens_ops = (input, target)
   2461         if any([type(t) is not Tensor for t in tens_ops]) and has_torch_function(tens_ops):
-> 2462             return handle_torch_function(
   2463                 cross_entropy, tens_ops, input, target, weight=weight,
   2464                 size_average=size_average, ignore_index=ignore_index, reduce=reduce,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/overrides.py in handle_torch_function(public_api, relevant_args, *args, **kwargs)
   1058         # Use `public_api` instead of `implementation` so __torch_function__
   1059         # implementations can do equality/identity comparisons.
-> 1060         result = overloaded_arg.__torch_function__(public_api, types, args, kwargs)
   1061 
   1062         if result is not NotImplemented:

~/fastai/fastai/torch_core.py in __torch_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs)
    317 #         if func.__name__[0]!='_': print(func, types, args, kwargs)
    318 #         with torch._C.DisableTorchFunction(): ret = _convert(func(*args, **(kwargs or {})), self.__class__)
--> 319         ret = super().__torch_function__(func, types, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    320         if isinstance(ret, TensorBase): ret.set_meta(self, as_copy=True)
    321         return ret

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in __torch_function__(cls, func, types, args, kwargs)
    993 
    994         with _C.DisableTorchFunction():
--> 995             ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
    996             return _convert(ret, cls)
    997 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2466     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2467         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2468     return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
   2469 
   2470 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2262                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   2263     if dim == 2:
-> 2264         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2265     elif dim == 4:
   2266         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)

IndexError: Target 2 is out of bounds.
```

#### Code

While in the `learn.fit_one_cycle(3, lr_max=1e-3)` it shows the error message above. I am sure that for both the training set and the validation set have the same labels by checking `len(df[df['is_valid']==False]['label'].unique()) == len(df[df['is_valid']==True]['label'].unique())` and print them respectively.

```
import os
import torch
from transformers import *
from fastai.text.all import *

from blurr.data.all import *
from blurr.modeling.all import *

task = HF_TASKS_AUTO.SequenceClassification
pretrained_model_name = "bert-base-uncased"
hf_arch, hf_config, hf_tokenizer, hf_model = BLURR_MODEL_HELPER.get_hf_objects(pretrained_model_name,  task=task)

# data loader
blocks = (HF_TextBlock(hf_arch, hf_config, hf_tokenizer, hf_model),  CategoryBlock)
dblock = DataBlock(blocks=blocks,  
                   get_x=ColReader('texts'), 
                   get_y=ColReader('label'), 
                   splitter=ColSplitter('is_valid'))

dls = dblock.dataloaders(df, batch_size=4)
```

```
model = HF_BaseModelWrapper(hf_model)

learn = Learner(dls, 
                model,
                opt_func=partial(Adam, decouple_wd=True),
                loss_func=CrossEntropyLossFlat(),
                metrics=[accuracy, F1Score(average='macro')],
                cbs=[HF_BaseModelCallback],
                splitter=hf_splitter)

learn.create_opt()  
learn.freeze()

learn.fit_one_cycle(3, lr_max=1e-3)
```

Has anyone gotten some similar problems before? and is there anything I lost in the code?